# Add Class To Body On Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to the body tag just on the homepage and that it. However, it's not working. What am I doing wring?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
          if(window.location.href===window.location.hostname) {
               $("body").addClass("home");
           }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need `jQuery` to do that?

Comment: No. I actually thought plain old javascript would work better.

Comment: Why not set class in the HTML markup? `<body class="home">`

Comment: I'm wondering how you debug it, seems easy to see what's going wrong

Comment: @anmarti as mentioned, just homepage only.

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't know how to debug.

Comment: @anmarti http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.href` will never be the same as `window.location.hostname` since the former will contain protocol part (e.g.: http://) where as the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think

```
if(window.location.href===window.location.hostname) {
}
```

will ever be true. hostname will host be something like stackoverflow.com where href will include protocol, ports and other things that may be apart of full url. You want to check if

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("home.html") != -1) {
}
```

Or something of that nature. But as pointed out in comment this seems much simpler to just add to that html file or do it on the server if you generate the HTML.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace You may have many pages with URL ending with `home.html`

Comment: @MaxZoom absolutely true. That's why I said something of that nature since I'm not familiar with structure and naming of his pages.

Answer (score 2):

`window.location.href` contains protocol information and will never equal `window.location.hostname`

As per [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

> - window.location.href returns the href (URL) of the current page
> - window.location.hostname returns the domain name of the web host
> - window.location.pathname returns the path and filename of the current    page

You should rather check the `pathname` for home page location:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (path == '/' || path == '/home.html') {
  $("body").addClass("home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without jquery very easy.

```
window.addEventListener("load", MyFunction);
function MyFunction(){
  if(window.location.origin == window.location.href) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    body[0].className = "myclass";
  }
}
```

or

```
window.addEventListener("load", MyFunction);
function MyFunction(){
  if(window.location.origin == window.location.href) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = "myclass";
  }
}
```

`body[0]` because `document.getElementsByTagName` return value is an array.

Comment: You forgot the part where he checks if the page is the homepage though

Answer (score 0):

With the comments being made, it got me thinking. I tried this and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        switch (window.location.pathname) {
          case '':
          case '/index.php':
              $('body').addClass('home')
        }
    });
</script>
```

I forgot to mention in the question that it is on a PHP powered website. I answered my own question to help others who one day might have the exact same question.